# Not getting value back by s:hidden

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hidden

I am using struts2 tag s:hidden to store a List of Object and an Object as hidden fields.
I have created getters and setters for both but when I am trying to use this List or Object back I am getting null;

```
<s:hidden id="productTypes" name="productTypes" value="%{productTypes}"></s:hidden>
```

this is how I am declaring productTypes which is a list a hidden variable.

and here is getters and setters...

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getProductTypes() {
        return productTypes;
    }

    public void setProductTypes(List<Map<String, Object>> productTypes) {
        this.productTypes = productTypes;
    }
```

I dont know what I am missing here.

Comment: You can't store a list (that way) with `<s:hidden>`. It would be better to use requests or sessions to store complex objects like lists or maps.

Comment: HTTP only sends strings, if you want to recreate a map you'd need to either use normal input naming with multiple elements, or have a scheme to convert from a single string into the complex object. The other option is putting the list in session.

Comment: Going with daves suggestion of a conversion scheme json would be easiest, type converters already exist.